# Magento 2 hide button Search from Grid(Created using block)

Tags: magento2, grid

I want to hide Search button from admin grid which is created using blocks and not ui component,

How should do I that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search button is added in a core file

at

```
vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Grid.php
```

with function

```
public function getSearchButtonHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('search_button');
}
```

So in my module's grid file I have added same function as follows to remove Search button

```
public function getSearchButtonHtml()
{
    return '';
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: between you should not use block for creating admin grid its outdated.. the best practice is to use ui component.

Comment: Hello @Pramod I have created  grid inside report section so used block

Comment: you might have only added a column over there ?